# Updating Firebase Data in Real-Time and Handling Flip-Cards with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on a project where I'm generating flip-cards to display data from a Firebase database. Using the `innerHTML` property, I create the cards based on the number of wells present in the database. The cards are created successfully, but I'm facing two issues.

1. Real-Time Data Update: When I update any data in the Firebase database, the changes are not reflected in real-time within the HTML code, even though I can see the updates in the console.
2. Flip-Card Script Issue: I'm using a flip-card script to handle the flipping animation for the cards. However, the script doesn't work correctly when there are multiple cards present. How could I modify the script to work for each specific card individually?

This is all my code:

```js
function addCard() {
  var firebase = "https://sienapa-734e9-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/data/pozos.json"
  var datos_pozo = new EventSource(firebase);
  datos_pozo.addEventListener('put', function(e) {
    var json = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(json);
    if (json.path == "/") {
      dbody = document.getElementById("container-flip-card-body");
      for (var key in json.data) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var h5_f = document.createElement("h5");
        var p_1 = document.createElement("p");
        var p_2 = document.createElement("p");
        var div_button = document.createElement("div");
        var h5_b = document.createElement("h5");
        var p_3 = document.createElement("p");
        var p_4 = document.createElement("p");
        var p_5 = document.createElement("p");
        var p_6 = document.createElement("p");
        var button = document.createElement("div");

        //Agregar las clases de cada elemento
        div.classList.add("flip-card");
        p_1.setAttribute("id", key);
        h5_f.classList.add("card-title");
        p_1.classList.add("card-text", "estado");
        p_2.classList.add("card-text", "electricidad");
        div_button.classList.add("d-grid", "gap-2");
        h5_b.classList.add("card-title");
        p_3.classList.add("card-text");
        p_4.classList.add("card-text");
        p_5.classList.add("card-text");
        p_6.classList.add("card-text");

        //Insertar valores por medio de innerHTML
        //var str = json.data[key].nombre;
        //var title_name = str.split(' ').join('');

        h5_f.innerHTML = json.data[key].nombre;
        //var estado = json.data[key].estado_pozo.estado;
        p_1.innerHTML = "<b>Estado:</b> " + json.data[key].estado_pozo.estado;
        //var electricidad = json.data[key].estado_pozo.electricidad;
        p_2.innerHTML = "<b>Electricidad:</b> " + json.data[key].estado_pozo.electricidad;
        div_button.innerHTML = `<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" formmethod="post"><i class="bi bi-power"></i></button>
                                      <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="flipCard()">Mas información</button>`;
        h5_b.innerHTML = json.data[key].nombre;
        p_3.innerHTML = "<b>Convenio:</b> " + json.data[key].convenio;
        p_4.innerHTML = "<b>Concesión:</b> " + json.data[key].concesion;
        p_5.innerHTML = "<b>Ubicación:</b> " + json.data[key].ubicacion;
        p_6.innerHTML = "<b>Información extra:</b> " + json.data[key].informacion;
        button.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="flipCard()">Regresar</button>';


        // Unir todo
        div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <img src="https://telegra.ph/file/c19f88650a45e2c393ceb.png" class="gota">
                ${h5_f.outerHTML}
                ${p_1.outerHTML}
                ${p_2.outerHTML}
                ${div_button.outerHTML}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <img src="/static/img/gotas.png" class="gota">
                ${h5_b.outerHTML}
                ${p_3.outerHTML}
                ${p_4.outerHTML}
                ${p_5.outerHTML}
                ${p_6.outerHTML}
                ${button.outerHTML}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
        //Agregar el contenido al HTML
        dbody.appendChild(div);

        document.getElementById(key).value = json.data[key].estado_pozo.estado;
      }
    } else {
      s = json.path.split("/");
      console.log(s[1]);
      console.log(json.data);
      document.getElementById(s[1]).value = json.data;
    }
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.titulo {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content_cards {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  color: #000;
  padding: 25px;
}

.flip-card {
  perspective: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.flip-card.flipped .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #ccc;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.icon-switch:before {
  content: "\e9b6";
}

.gota {
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lista de Pozos</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/static/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="titulo">Lista de Pozos</h1>
  <div class="container-flip-card" id="container-flip-card-body">

  </div>

  <script>
    function flipCard() {
      var flipCard = document.querySelector('.flip-card');
      flipCard.classList.toggle('flipped');
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      addCard();
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```